# Sorting empty values last instead of first

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sorting, stored-procedures

I am trying to implement a sorting procedure which will sort according to the value of a drop down list. What happens is that when the list is being sorted, the NULL fields will be replaced by specified replacement value, in this case `''`. This is being sorted first because we are sorting ascendingly, now I would want to sort ascendingly *BUT* with null values LAST. How could I implement this?

```
ORDER BY l.IsActive DESC, 
        CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 1 THEN n.DisplayName
             WHEN @SortOrder = 2 THEN CASE ec.IsEquipmentRelated
                                            WHEN  1 THEN ISNULL(el.ShopID,'') + 
                                                    ISNULL(ec.EquipmentAbbr,'') + 
                                                    ISNULL(el.ClassSequenceNumber,'') + 
                                                    ISNULL(el.EquipmentComponent,'') + 
                                                    ISNULL(el.CompSequenceNumber,'')
                                            WHEN  0 THEN ISNULL(ec.EquipmentAbbr,'')
                                            ELSE NULL
                                      END
             ELSE l.DisplayName
        END
```

Edit: Running MS SQL Server 2008 / T-SQL

**Edit:** @Joe Stefanelli, I have tried this, it's not compiling:

```
ORDER BY l.IsActive DESC, 
    CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 0 THEN l.DisplayName
         WHEN @SortOrder = 1 THEN CASE WHEN n.DisplayName = '' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, n.DisplayName
         WHEN @SortOrder = 2 THEN 
                                  CASE ec.IsEquipmentRelated
                                        WHEN  1 THEN ISNULL(el.ShopID,'') + 
                                            ISNULL(ec.EquipmentAbbr,'') + 
                                            ISNULL(el.ClassSequenceNumber,'') + 
                                            ISNULL(el.EquipmentComponent,'') + 
                                            ISNULL(el.CompSequenceNumber,'')
                                        WHEN  0 THEN ISNULL(ec.EquipmentAbbr,'')
                                        ELSE NULL
                                  END
     END
```

Comment: @Matthew Cox the tsql tag indicates to me that its SQL Server. Although which version could help

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN YourField = '' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, YourField
```

Comment: I don't really understand the `THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,` part... Are you simplifying?

Comment: @JFB: I'm just introducing an artificial element for sorting purposes. When your field is an empty string, we use 2 else 1. So, envision the sorting ending up as something like `(1, 'alpha'), (1, 'bravo'), ..., (1, 'zulu'), (2, '')`

Comment: ok... I have tried this approach, please look at my edit above.

Comment: this is SQL query trick, it is basically sorting by 2 column first column is the artifical one based on case, second column is ur column by choice

Answer (score 3):

Best way is to add a derived column that would have sort order values (CASE that checks whether the other column is null) and then order by that column.

Answer (score 2):

Your second snippet will not compile because you are trying to return more than one value in the `WHEN @SortOrder = 1` branch of the outer CASE. You could fix it if you made a couple of tiny changes to the said branch:

1. Change `2` and `1` to , for example,`'2'` and `'1'` respectively.
2. Replace the comma (`,`) with the concatenation operator (`+`).

And so the resulting ORDER BY clause would look like this:

```
ORDER BY
  l.IsActive DESC, 
  CASE
    WHEN @SortOrder = 0 THEN l.DisplayName
    WHEN @SortOrder = 1 THEN
      CASE WHEN n.DisplayName = '' THEN '2' ELSE '1' END + n.DisplayName
    WHEN @SortOrder = 2 THEN 
      CASE ec.IsEquipmentRelated
        WHEN  1 THEN
          ISNULL(el.ShopID,'') + 
          ISNULL(ec.EquipmentAbbr,'') + 
          ISNULL(el.ClassSequenceNumber,'') + 
          ISNULL(el.EquipmentComponent,'') + 
          ISNULL(el.CompSequenceNumber,'')
        WHEN  0 THEN
          ISNULL(ec.EquipmentAbbr,'')
        ELSE NULL
      END
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

OK! I have found out a way to solve this using all three answers combined. +1 for each answer! What I did is first to create a 'virtual' derived column, assigning null values to 1 and non-null values to 0, sorting that first, then sorting out the rest:

```
ORDER BY 
   l.IsActive DESC, 
   CASE
    WHEN @SortOrder = 0 THEN (Case When l.DisplayName Is Null Then 1 Else 0 End)
    WHEN @SortOrder = 1 THEN (Case When n.DisplayName Is Null Then 1 Else 0 End)
    WHEN @SortOrder = 2 THEN (Case When ec.EquipmentAbbr Is Null Then 1 Else 0 End)
   END,
   CASE 
      WHEN @SortOrder = 0 THEN l.DisplayName
      WHEN @SortOrder = 1 THEN n.DisplayName
      WHEN @SortOrder = 2 THEN 
               ISNULL(el.ShopID,'') + 
               ISNULL(ec.EquipmentAbbr,'') + 
               ISNULL(el.ClassSequenceNumber,'') + 
               ISNULL(el.EquipmentComponent,'') + 
               ISNULL(el.CompSequenceNumber,'')
   END
```

This way, the sorting of if a field is null or not is done before the actual sorting is done, which brings the null values at the end.